# Add type defintions file for a library

Tags: typescript

I'm want to use mocha-given in my current project written in typescript, so I need type definitions for it. I forked mocha-given and created a new file in it called "mocha-given.d.ts" with the definitions I need.

Now, back at my other project, I want to use mocha-given, but the typescript compiler fails because it can't find the "mocha-given.d.ts" file (I installed it from my forked project and the file is there).

How do I tell the typescript compiler where it should find the definitions?

Answer (score 0):

Set the typings-folder in the tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots" : ["./typings"]
    }
}
```

You can find more information about the tsconfig.json [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)